# Move array objects/elements Up and Down by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an list of values with up and down button. If i want to click up button the element with move upwards with previous value in list and i click down button they moves downwards to next item in list. my sample code is here,

```
<ul>
  <li> 1 &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="up">UP</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="down">DOWN</button></li>
  <li> 2 &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="up">UP</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="down">DOWN</button></li>
  <li> 3 &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="up">UP</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="down">DOWN</button></li>
  <li> 4 &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="up">UP</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="down">DOWN</button></li>
  <li> 5 &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="up">UP</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="down">DOWN</button></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function moveUp(element) {
  if(element.previousElementSibling)
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(element, element.previousElementSibling);
}
function moveDown(element) {
  if(element.nextElementSibling)
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(element.nextElementSibling, element);
}
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.className === 'down') moveDown(e.target.parentNode);
  else if(e.target.className === 'up') moveUp(e.target.parentNode);
});
    </script>
```

This is the code with list of values to display, but i want array values to display in this format which performs up and down function based on index. 
my array element is:

```
[
    { id: "Racer-101", rank: "1"},
    { id: "Racer-102", rank: "2"},
    { id: "Racer-103", rank: "3"},
    { id: "Racer-104", rank: "4"},
    { id: "Racer-105", rank: "5"},
    { id: "Racer-106", rank: "6"},
    { id: "Racer-107", rank: "7"},
    { id: "Racer-108", rank: "8"},
    { id: "Racer-109", rank: "9"}
]
```

how is it possible with array values..

Comment: Well you shouldn't updated your question with the code from the answer, it will be confusing, But anyway, I don't see any bindings of the `moveUp()` and `moveDown()` functions with buttons in your code.

Comment: I will update my first coding, my main problem is to display this array values in table. how to define the array values in table with this function, this up and down function perform on click.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to perform the same thing with your `array`, all you need to do is to check if the given `element` has a `previous` or a `next` element so you can swap both objects to avoid `an index out of bound`.

This is how should be your code:

```
function moveUp(id) {
  let index = arr.findIndex(e => e.id == id);
  if (index > 0) {
    let el = arr[index];
    arr[index] = arr[index - 1];
    arr[index - 1] = el;
  }
}
```

To **move an `element` up** in the `array`, you need to make sure this `element` **isn't the first** element in the `array`, then perform the swap operation.

```
function moveDown(id) {
  let index = arr.findIndex(e => e.id == id);
  if (index !== -1 && index < arr.length - 1) {
    let el = arr[index];
    arr[index] = arr[index + 1];
    arr[index + 1] = el;
  }
}
```

To **move an `element` down**, you need to make sure this **`element` isn't the last one** in the `array`.

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo sample:

```js
var arr = [
    { id: "Racer-101", rank: "1"},
    { id: "Racer-102", rank: "2"},
    { id: "Racer-103", rank: "3"},
    { id: "Racer-104", rank: "4"},
    { id: "Racer-105", rank: "5"},
    { id: "Racer-106", rank: "6"},
    { id: "Racer-107", rank: "7"},
    { id: "Racer-108", rank: "8"},
    { id: "Racer-109", rank: "9"}
];

function moveUp(id) {
  let index = arr.findIndex(e => e.id == id);
  if (index > 0) {
    let el = arr[index];
    arr[index] = arr[index - 1];
    arr[index - 1] = el;
  }
}

function moveDown(id) {
  let index = arr.findIndex(e => e.id == id);
  if (index !== -1 && index < arr.length - 1) {
    let el = arr[index];
    arr[index] = arr[index + 1];
    arr[index + 1] = el;
  }
}
moveDown("Racer-101");
moveUp("Racer-103");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It works fine, but i want to display all array values in table with up and down buttons in every row. Based on clicking button in the row to change previous and next position in the table..

Comment: @NewUSer I don't have any experience with knockout, but all you have to do is to pass the `id` to the `moveUp()` and `moveDown` functions correctly.

Comment: ok, how is it possible to display this array values in  table using jquery with click function. Is any other methods to bind data in the table..

Comment: Please update your question, with the relevant Knockout code, you ahve tried. Normally if you call the functions from your Knockout code, it will handle the rendering dynamically.